# Crystal Report Viewer for vs 2012 express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, visual-studio-express

i have install visual studio 2012 express for window. I want to view some existing crystal report (rpt) file but i am unable to open that file in VS 2012 express. Is there any way to install  Crystal Report or Crystal Report Viewer in VS 2012 express. please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[SAP Crystal Reports, Developer Version for Visual Studio .NET does NOT support Express Editions of any version of Visual Studio .NET.](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

You can download the free [visual studio community edition 2013](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) which work well with crystal report